# CSS - Element with visibility:hidden doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a wrapper and an inner-wrapper as a child element of the wrapper. The inner-wrapper should scroll inside the wrapper and should have visibility hidden.

This works fine in computer browsers. However, the inner wrapper doesn't scroll when I open the page in a mobile browser.

What is the problem?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id = "inner-wrapper">
    <div id = "circle"></div>
    <div id = rectangle></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>
  button
</button>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 99999999;
}

#inner-wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99999999;
}
#circle{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 99999999;

}
#rectangle{
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 99999999;

}
button{
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/934v8g69/

Comment: Some mobile browsers don't support scrolling by anything other than the entire page.

Comment: When i set inner-wrapper's property visibility:visible, it scrolls. However, this is not correct value for this property, according to the specifications of the project.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using the following property:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Also be sure to set:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: this property didn't help me.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet ? Also, can you help me understand what you are trying to achieve a little better ?

Comment: I added the code in the question. As you can see, the button is visible but we cannot click on it. The problem is solved when I use the property visibility: hidden in inner-wrapper and visibility: visible in circle and rectangle. Howevert, this is not working in mobiles.